Mysql Displaying null instead of 0
blhfeedback TABLE



learningHub_Login
blh_feedbck_barangay_locationID




Bagong Silang
1


Bagong Silang
1


Bagong Silang
1


Tuyo
25



blh_location Table



blh_feedbck_barangay_locationID
blh_barangay
blh_if_faciility_open




1
Bagong Silang
1


2
Tenejero
1


24
Cupang North
0


25
Tuyo
1



I'm trying to combine the Count of "LearningHub_Login" column from the  blhfeedback table and the blh_if_faciility_open column form the blh_location table using the query below
SELECT
    COUNT( blhfeedback.LearningHub_LogIn ) AS 'Total User for Today,',
    blh_location.blh_kung_meronngFacility AS 'Active Facility?'
FROM
    blhfeedback
    INNER JOIN blh_location ON blhfeedback.blh_feedbck_barangay_locationID = blh_location.barangay_location_id
WHERE
    DATE( blhfeedback.Login_info_Open ) = DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY ) ) 
    AND
    blhfeedback.LearningHub_LogIn = 'Bagong Silang'

and i successfully combine them and display the column i desired like this



Total User for Today
Active Facility?




3
1



but may change my
blhfeedback.LearningHub_LogIn='Bagong Silang'

to
 blhfeedback.LearningHub_LogIn='Tenejero'
 /* OR CHANGE TENEJERO TO THIS */
 blhfeedback.LearningHub_LogIn='Cupang North'

I'm getting a value of 'Null istead the balue of blh_if_faciility_open TABLE LIKE THIS



Total User for Today
Active Facility?




0
Null



Is it possible to get the value of  blh_if_faciility_open TABLE to my query? or i just made the wrong Mysql jOIN IN MY COMMAND?

Kumusta! - Off-topic tip: I recommend you use short table-aliases, so you don't end-up repeating  the full table-name blhfeedback anywhere. e.g. FROM blhfeedback AS bf INNER JOIN blh_location AS bl ON bf.etc - you might want to rename blh_feedbck_barangay_locationID to be shorter too...

If you filter on "blhfeedback.LearningHub_LogIn='Tenejero'" you should actually get no rows altogether... as you don't have that value in your "blhfeedback" table. Is your test environment here on SO missing some other tables?

SELECT
    count(blhfeedback.LearningHub_LogIn) as 'Total User for Today,', IFNULL(blh_location.blh_kung_meronngFacility,0) as 'Active Facility?'
    FROM blhfeedback
    INNER JOIN blh_location ON blhfeedback.blh_feedbck_barangay_locationID = blh_location.barangay_location_id
    WHERE date(blhfeedback.Login_info_Open)=date(date_sub(now(),interval 0 day)) 
    AND blhfeedback.LearningHub_LogIn='Bagong Silang'

Use IFNULL() on 'Active Facility?'

when i use IFNULL() on 'Active Facility?' and change the
blhfeedback.LearningHub_LogIn='Tenejero'
I'm getting a 0 Value instead the 1 value as shown in the  blh_if_faciility_open column

That is correct since blhfeedback TABLE  does not have "learningHub_Login" which has a value 'Tenejero'.
Avoid using string as reference and instead use foreign key to table relationships
You are using inner join so 'Tenejero' should exists on both table.
Like 'Bagong Silang' exists on both table which your able to grab value from it..
Hence your using string this is prone to issues like 'bagong silang' which will also result to 0 zero because of case sensitivity
